# MongoDB: what is the difference between $elemMatch and $and to find objects inside array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there any logical difference between the usage of the query operator `$and`

```
db.collection.find({$and: [{"array.field1": "someValue"}, {"array.field2": 3}]})
```

and the usage of the projection operator `$elemMatch`

```
db.collection.find({array: {$elemMatch: {field1: "someValue", field2: 3}}})
```

to find documents which contain the object fields inside an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first query will find documents, where array have at least one element with field1= somevalue and at least one element with field2=3. Both elements can be different.
The second one will retrieve documents where array have at least one  element matching the two conditions simultaneously. 
Here's a data sample to explain :

```
   {
    array: [
      {
        field1: 1,   
      },
      {
        field2: 2
      },
      {
        field1: 1,
        field2: 3
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    array: [
      {
        field1: 1,
        field2: 2
      },
      {
        field2: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    array: [
      {
        field1: 1,
        field2: "other"
      },
      {
        field2: 2
      }
    ]
  }
```

The first query

> db.collection.find({"array.field1": 1,"array.field2": 2})  (equivalent
>   to your $and syntax)

will returne the three documents,

> db.collection.find({array: {$elemMatch: {field1: 1, field2: 2}}})

will return only the second document (the only one having an element matching both criterias)

EDIT : The logical operator of the first query is OR, for the second one it's AND, at level of array element.

Answer (score 9):

I will explain this with an example. Consider the collection `arrays`. It has a field called `arr` which is *an array of embedded documents* (with fields `a` and `b`).

Some documents in the `arrays` collection:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "arr" : [ { "a" : "a1", "b" : "b1" }, { "a" : "a2", "b" : "b2" } ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "arr" : [ { "a" : "a1", "b" : "b11" }, { "a" : "a2", "b" : "b22" } ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "arr" : [ { "a" : "a2", "b" : "b1" }, { "a" : "a", "b" : "b1" } ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "arr" : [ { "a" : "a1", "b" : "b91" }, { "a" : "a29", "b" : "b1" } ] }
```

I want to find all documents with the array embedded-document fields `a="a1"` AND `b="b1"`. Note this must be within the same element embedded-document of the array. I use **$elemMatch** for this and get the desired result.

```
> db.arrays.find( { arr: { $elemMatch: { a: "a1", b: "b1" } } } )
==>
{ "_id" : 1, "arr" : [ { "a" : "a1", "b" : "b1" }, { "a" : "a2", "b" : "b2" } ] }
```

Now, if I use the **$and** operator like in the following query, the results are not correct. As you can see an additional document is selected. The query worked with the array embedded-document fields `a="a1"` OR `b="b1"`.

```
> db.arrays.find({$and: [ { "arr.a": "a1" }, { "arr.b": "b1" } ] } )
==>
{ "_id" : 1, "arr" : [ { "a" : "a1", "b" : "b1" }, { "a" : "a2", "b" : "b2" } ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "arr" : [ { "a" : "a1", "b" : "b91" }, { "a" : "a29", "b" : "b1" } ] }
```

So, using the `$and` operator is NOT intended for this purpose (i.e., querying on multiple fields of an array of sub-documents).

Also, to query on an array embedded-document field (**only one field**) the `$elemMatch` is not required, for example:

```
> db.arrays.find( { "arr.a": "a2" } )
==>
{ "_id" : 1, "arr" : [ { "a" : "a1", "b" : "b1" }, { "a" : "a2", "b" : "b2" } ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "arr" : [ { "a" : "a1", "b" : "b11" }, { "a" : "a2", "b" : "b22" } ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "arr" : [ { "a" : "a2", "b" : "b1" }, { "a" : "a", "b" : "b1" } ] }
```