# mongodb count(*) is not using compound index

Tags: mongodb

> select count(*) from dataset where actors.lastName="Smith" and
>   actors.roles="TRAVELER"

i have compound index created on `actors.lastName` and `actors.roles
count(*)` is very slow. How to force mongo to use compound index and improve performance?

There are no other indexes created by me on this collection.
MongoDB query:

```
use test;
db.getCollection("dataset").aggregate(
     [
      { 
          "$match" : {
             "actors.lastName" : "Smith", 
             "actors.roles" : "TRAVELER"
          }
      }, 
      { 
          "$group" : {
            "_id" : {
           }, 
          "COUNT(*)" : {
                "$sum" : NumberInt(1)
            }
       }
     }, 
    { 
        "$project" : {
            "COUNT(*)" : "$COUNT(*)", 
            "_id" : NumberInt(0)
        }
    }
    ], 
   { 
      "allowDiskUse" : true
   }
     );
```

if i test
`select  count(*) from dataset where actors.lastname="Smith"`
count(*) is fast, and it uses the index created on `actors.lastname`.

mongodb version 4.0.9

count(*) is very slow. How to force mongo to use compound index and improve performance?

Comment: why does your question have `enter code here` all over the place?

Comment: unable to format it...when i press ctlr-k i get these. If i remove then post fails due to formating problem....pls ignore this repeated text.

Comment: Are you issuing the aggregation command direction, or is there some library / tool that is converting the SQL statement to the aggregation?

Comment: can you provide sample data? (is actors.roles an array?) . And are you sure it doesn't use index? Did you perform an explain()?

Comment: May be you can try COUNT(*) as shown in [$group stage examples of MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) and see what happens.

Comment: Also, do a `db.collection.getIndexes()` and  post the compound index definition.

Comment: There is also a [db.collection.count( {...} )](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/index.html) function.

Comment: See this post about matching embedded document fields from an array: [MongoDB: what is the difference between $elemMatch and $and to find objects inside array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384199/mongodb-what-is-the-difference-between-elemmatch-and-and-to-find-objects-insi/58387242#58387242)

Comment: 1. db.collection.getIndexes() 
MongoDB server version: 4.0.9
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "test.pnrsearch"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "actors.lastName" : 1,
                        "actors.roles" : 1
                },
                "name" : "actors.lastName_1_actors.roles_1",
                "ns" : "test.pnrsearch"
        }
]

Comment: 2. db.collection.count() --->same high latency
3. i used a sql to mongo query convertor and also tried basic mongo query in both cases count(*) on multiple field is taking time
4. .explain fails on aggregate object
5. a simple query like select * from table where a="xx" and b=yy has good response and .explain shows it uses indexes

Comment: Can you share what the document looks like in the "dataset" collection (one sample)? Also, you may want to add additional info to the question post and formatted - for readability.

Comment: i hv huge data 
sample data:
{
        10KB of some block here split under different names...and then 
 "actors": [{
   "lastName": "Smith",
   "role": "TRAELER"
  },
  {
   "firstName": "Ragha",
   "role": "TRAVELER"
  }  
 ]
}
if i just simulate
{
 "actors": [{
   "lastName": "Smith",
   "role": "TRAELER"
  },
  {
   "firstName": "Ragha",
   "role": "TRAVELER"
  }  
 ]
}
No Issues